# Why am I getting "Object is possibly 'undefined'" in this optional chain?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optional-chaining

I got here:

```
buyTicketData?.pricingOptions
```

this error:

```
[tsl] ERROR in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/tikex/tikexModule/components/BuyTicket/PricingOptionInvoiceItemsFormFieldsCheckboxes.tsx(280,25)
      TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Why it matters if left side of `?` is undefined, `?` wraps it, not?

here are the types:

```
buyTicketData?: BuyTicketData;

export type BuyTicketData = {
  pricingOptions?: PricingOptions;
}

export type PricingOptions = {
  [optionId: string]: PricingOptionType;
};

export type PricingOptionType = {
  invoiceItems?: InvoiceItems;
};

export type InvoiceItems = {
  [invoiceItemId: string]: InvoiceItemData;
};

export type InvoiceItemData = {
  defaultValue?: number;
};
```

This is the whole expression anyway

```js
<select
value={
startPaymentIn?.invoiceItems?.[key] != undefined
  ? startPaymentIn?.invoiceItems?.[key] == 1
    ? "Igen"
    : "Nem"
  : startPaymentIn?.pricingOptionId &&
    buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[ // <-- here
      startPaymentIn!.pricingOptionId!
    ].invoiceItems[key]?.defaultValue != undefined
  ? startPaymentIn?.pricingOptionId &&
    buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[
      startPaymentIn!.pricingOptionId!
    ].invoiceItems[key]?.defaultValue == 1
    ? "Igen"
    : "Nem"
  : undefined
}
```

---

OK, find the solution:

```js
value={
  startPaymentIn?.invoiceItems?.[key] != undefined
    ? startPaymentIn?.invoiceItems?.[key] == 1
      ? "Igen"
      : "Nem"
    : buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[
        startPaymentIn?.pricingOptionId ?? ""
      ]?.invoiceItems?.[key]?.defaultValue != undefined
    ? buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[
        startPaymentIn?.pricingOptionId ?? ""
      ]?.invoiceItems?.[key]?.defaultValue == 1
      ? "Igen"
      : "Nem"
    : undefined
}
```

I just do not know why this ugly `?? ""` condition need.

Comment: You could write a custom tag to do this.

Comment: It would help both you and us if you provided a [mre].

Comment: Ok, I produced a [mre] for you, in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70705246/8910547).

Comment: Janos, I think this is a bit unfair, because you approved the answer that didn't actually fix the problem *as you stated it*. That's the problem when you don't supply an [mre]. I took your code as-is, and isolated the part that was generating the error in the question title, and provided a fix. The answer you approved solved a different problem: not having to use the `!` operator in your expression (which you didn't mention was an issue. Maybe in the actual code context those were fine). In other words, I wasted time carefully solving you problem as stated and writing out an answer. 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `a` is `undefined`, `a.b` throws exception while `a?.b` resolves to `undefined`. You still need to handle the `undefined`.

```
buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[startPaymentIn?.pricingOptionId]
```

resolves to

```
buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[undefined]
```

if `startPaymentIn` is `undefined`. This would throw error as `undefined` cannot be a key.

A better way is to do a null check before everything if this variable is essential, so that you don't need `?.` at all.

```
if(startPaymentIn)
{
    //no need to use ?. on startPayment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed one optional chaining operator for the possibly undefined `invoiceItems`. The `defaultValue` lookup should be like this:

```
buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[startPaymentIn!.pricingOptionId!]
    .invoiceItems?.[key]?.defaultValue
```

The following [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) illustrates this. [Try it in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBCBXRAVAlgYwGtgYARAQxnLgF44BvAKDhbjCgNwDsBzAeTAxcELgGcA-AC44ABQ75u-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-MR4AQg5jjOC5UBoIUMlrBMA3IZNiwXVsV3bHMuw3OdQRUfs9yHfoRwzE9g2wpC8MuT9WElGA1S4d4aI7XNAS4YM2KmEpOOARBvDgfM6GxBD3xcIjWHEMTPlotcpJkg92JqBSlNoOgAEZtIyFhdIAIicKCuAc2y7OkByADlijcuzWGGfSJPoiimyCVw4AhCF3OI+N-QbLcmPTJcYv8vTV0k7tErTLh+1SlhWJMuTF2PRTvG4vYcOQ-CVLUrgNK4YAtLSuzdLbYL11C3twpcSLopalqSPi2dsubEr8oG9q6PXTdKJ3fMJoyQrWmK8zyqDHjcJQgjrMWnS4Ccly-IG-zPJ8opjpO6R1L2TS6iAA) to see the errors.

```js
export type BuyTicketData = {
    pricingOptions?: PricingOptions;
}

export type PricingOptions = {
    [optionId: string]: PricingOptionType;
};

export type PricingOptionType = {
    invoiceItems?: InvoiceItems
}

export type InvoiceItems = {
    [invoiceItemId: string]: InvoiceItemData
}

export type InvoiceItemData = {
    defaultValue?: number
}

let startPaymentIn: PricingOptionType & { pricingOptionId?: string } = {}

function testContext (key: string, buyTicketData?: BuyTicketData) {

    // incrementally testing your expression until we isolate the actual error
    let w = buyTicketData?.pricingOptions
    let x = buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[startPaymentIn!.pricingOptionId!]
    let y = buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[startPaymentIn!.pricingOptionId!].invoiceItems
    let z = buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[startPaymentIn!.pricingOptionId!].invoiceItems[key]
    // ^^^ error on this last line
    
    // the correct expression to get the `defaultValue`
    const defaultValue =
        buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[startPaymentIn!.pricingOptionId!].invoiceItems?.[key]?.defaultValue

    return startPaymentIn?.invoiceItems?.[key] != undefined
        ? startPaymentIn?.invoiceItems?.[key] == 1
            ? "Igen"
            : "Nem"
        : startPaymentIn?.pricingOptionId &&
          buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[
              startPaymentIn!.pricingOptionId!
              ].invoiceItems?.[key]?.defaultValue != undefined
            ? startPaymentIn?.pricingOptionId &&
              buyTicketData?.pricingOptions?.[
                  startPaymentIn!.pricingOptionId!
                  ].invoiceItems?.[key]?.defaultValue == 1
                ? "Igen"
                : "Nem"
            : undefined
}
```